# Can't tune Naive Bayes' smoothness hyperparameter in tidymodels

Tags: tidymodels

I can't seem to set `smoothness` to tune as a hyperparameter in `naive_Bayes()`, whereas I'm able to do so with other models such as `multinom_reg`. What am I doing wrong?

```r
library(tidymodels)
  library(reprex)
  
  
  nb_spec <- naive_Bayes(smoothness = tune()) %>%
    set_engine('klaR') %>%
    set_mode('classification')
  nb_spec %>% extract_parameter_set_dials()
#> Collection of 0 parameters for tuning
#> 
#> [1] identifier type       object    
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
  
  multinom_spec <- multinom_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>%
    set_engine('glmnet') %>% 
    set_mode('classification')
  multinom_spec %>% extract_parameter_set_dials()
#> Collection of 2 parameters for tuning
#> 
#>  identifier    type    object
#>     penalty penalty nparam[+]
#>     mixture mixture nparam[+]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `naive_Bayes()` engines are provided by the [discrim](https://discrim.tidymodels.org/) package, so you need to load that package to be able to extract the parameter set.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(discrim)

nb_spec <- naive_Bayes(smoothness = tune()) %>%
  set_engine('klaR') %>%
  set_mode('classification')
nb_spec %>% extract_parameter_set_dials()
#> Collection of 1 parameters for tuning
#> 
#>  identifier       type    object
#>  smoothness smoothness nparam[+]
```